# Dismissing keyboard, but not toolbar

Tags: keyboard, uitoolbar

I have a keyboard with a toolbar attached to it. It appears fine, but I would like one of the button in the toolbar to dismiss the keyboard, but leave the toolbar where it was above the keyboard and display something different where the keyboard was. How would I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly; but you can certain emulate it. Simply bring up a whole new toolbar and "something different" in your interface, behind the keyboard+toolbar, as the keyboard+toolbar is dismissed. You might even be able to make the keyboard's attached toolbar invisible so that it *looks* like it has just stayed in place because we see the identical toolbar behind it (but that's just a guess, I've never tried it).